# Jest tests fail and throw errors inconsistently and inconsistently fail pipeline

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

**Situation:**

1. I have a series of JEST tests that are testing against a react application with typescript.
2. Sometimes I will run the tests 8 times in a row and they will all pass. Then on the suddenly some of the tests will fail. Then sometimes all will pass but will throw errors.
3. When I have different people run them or different people share screen and watch the tests run, they are more likely to fail.

**Problem Description:**

- The failures are either that it cannot find an element by testId (in spite of the fact that it found it before) or that it's finding multiple (when multiple should not exist).
- The errors that are thrown are typically saying "Network Failed" or "TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'."

**Code**

All tests are some variation of this pattern:

```
describe('ice cream page', () => {
beforeEach(async () => {
await waitFor(async () => {
head().appendChild(createCSPNonceMeta('my-provided-nonce'));
nock('http://localhost:3000'.persist().get(//myapi/myv2/create-iceCream').reply(200, testIceCreamList);
});

it("create ice crea", async () +> {nock('http://localhost:3000).persist.post('/myapi/myv2/create-iceCream', testIceCreamRequest).reply(200, {fakeCreateIceCreamResponse});
});

await waitFor(async () => {
     let createIceCreamButton = screen.getByTestId('create-icecream-button');
     user.click(createIceCreamButton);
});

await waitFor(async () => {
     const createdIceCream = screen.queryByText(/vanilla/i);
     expect(createdIceCream).toBeInTheDocument();
     expect(createdIceCream).not.toBeNull;
});

});
```

**What I tried:**

1. I tried to have my test setup file fail loudly (as explained [here](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/1692)  ). I'm still getting the same output
2. Having set up / tear down methods in beforeEach/AfterEach (this makes no difference)
3. Breaking things into functions (which breaks things as well).
4. Adding nock.cleanAll(); afterEach

**Questions:**

1. How do I get these tests to pass consistently?
2. How do I get these tests to stop throwing errors?
3. Why are they failing inconsistently?
4. Why are they throwing errors?